# Labeling Builds in Vault with TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, sourcegear-vault

My VCS is Vault and I'm using TeamCity for my CI. I'd like to have TC label the project in vault upon a successful build but the documentation is not very clear on how to do this.

The actual TC documentation doesn't even list it as being supported by the labeling feature, but the plugin's dev page says it supports it. My concern is that if I turn on the labeling it will label the entire repository and not just the single project that is specified in the checkout rules.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Vault plugin whenever you apply a label, it will only be applied to what is set in your checkout rules.

Answer (score 0):

**TeamCity** (7.1 and earlier) does not support Vault Labeling according to this: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/VCS+Labeling.

I would like the same feature, see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-11066

...

Apparently Vault labeling IS supported, but not documented, see conclusion of TW-11066.